# Можно ли сделать многопоточную генерацию в transformer модели?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект, pytorch, code-generator

Есть вот такой код для генерации:

```
generation_config = GenerationConfig(
        top_p=0.0,
        top_k=1,
        temperature=0.0,
        max_new_tokens=600,
        pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id,
        eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
    )   

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    encoding = tokenizer(prompt, padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=20, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
    pp(encoding)

    with torch.inference_mode(): 
        outputs = model.generate(
            input_ids=encoding.input_ids,
            attention_mask=encoding.attention_mask,
            generation_config=generation_config,
        )
```

Пытался запустить генерацию 2-х разных запросов в 2-х разных потоках на одной модели, но получил ошибку `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x2 and 1x6400)`

Попробовал добавить падинг (думал, что проблема в разном размере массива инпут токенов), но вся та же ошибка

Вообще реально ли сделать такое, используя одну видеокарту? (Про batch inference знаю, просто интересен такой подход)